# How to center text if there isn't enough newlines to get text to the center in sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3

While coding in Sublime Text 3 if I get to the bottom of the page and try to use the `show_at_center` command I won't get able to get the current line all the way up to the center of the page because there isn't enough new lines. So I have to manually hit `enter` a bunch of times to get the text to come back up. Is there a way around this? Like some sort of command that: moves the text to the center of the screen even if there is only blank space below and no newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your user preferences (**`Preferences -> Settings-User`**) and add the following setting:

```js
"scroll_past_end": true
```

This allows you to keep scrolling the view all the way down until the last line is at the very top of the window.